# TDS2 column 3 “Amount which is subject to tax deduction”

Tags: india, income-tax

Please help?

I don’t get to see it—what to fill for the TDS2 column 3 “Amount which is subject to tax deduction”.

[image: **ITR1 - TDS2**]

Is it to fill there the FD Interest amount (= 54000, on which the TDS is made)

Answer (score 1):

> Is it to fill there the FD Interest amount (= 54000, on which the TDS is made)

Yes that is correct. You would need to fill the Interest on which the Bank has deducted the TDS.